# Bad design to keep track of objects instances with a static vector c++?

Tags: c++

The code which I am working with is creating a bunch of objects from a sensor class. When the application receives a questions like : "report all broken sensors" I am Iterating over all of my sensors objects with the help of a static vector inside my sensor class.

```
public:
static std::vector<Sensor*>objList;  
bool isBroken


std::vector<Sensor*>Sensor::objList; 

Sensor::Sensor(ComponentId, component Id....){
...
objList.push_back(this);
...
}

Sensor::IsBroken(){
isBroken = adValue == broken
}
```

Then we can respond with

```
bool Logger::BrokenSensors(std::string ComponentName){                                                                                                                                                       
    for ( auto i = Sensor::objList.begin(); i != Sensor::objList.end(); i++ ) {                                                                                                              
      if((*i)->GetStringId()==ComponentName){                                                                                                                                                                      
        return (*i)->isBroken;                                                                                                                                                                                 
      }                                                                                                                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                                                                                              
 return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

Is this considered to be bad practice? I cannot figure out a nicer way to do this. Also, the sensors objects are created from a bunch of difference places.

Comment: I don't consider it bad practice, but that's an opinion. This may be closed as off-topic since it may be considered an opinion-based question. Not the nicest code I've ever seen, but there's nothing against any rules. Off-topic: `BrokenSensors` should probably take in a `const std::string &` to avoid copying.

Comment: How do you assure that all the `Sensor*` point to objects that are still alive when you call `BrokenSensors`?

Comment: *Is this considered to be bad practice?* -- If the class will be used in a multithreaded environment *without synchronization of the static vector*, then yes, it is bad (or at least, dubious) practice.

Comment: @walnut They are only destroyed when the program is shutoff, and the question will only come after the sensor object is created.

Comment: why all those pointers? isn't a std::vector<Sensor> enough?

Comment: @mfnx `std::vector<Sensor>` is dangerous because of potential reallocation and reference invalidation when a new object is added. `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Sensor>>` or `std::list<Sensor>` would work fine though, I guess.

Comment: @mfnx It won't work due to slicing and the fact that `Sensor` most definitely **is** a base class and you can't really have runtime polymorphism without refs or pointers. And I would love to see code which actually has a `vector<T&>`. :D

Comment: your method `Sensor::IsBroken()` in combination with a public `isBroken` is something I would consider as broken. Why have a public member and the method? That requires callers to do `x.IsBroken();` and then check the value of `isBroken`. This can easily be used in a wrong way and I would push for a `bool IsBroken() { return adValue == broken;}` plus removing the public member

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this design can be improved. You should consider separating what a sensor is from how many sensors your system has. Introduce a `SensorManager` which takes care of managing sensor lifetime and leave your `Sensor` class to only care about what a sensor should do.

```
class SensorManager
{
    // maybe use a map<sensorid, shared_ptr<Sensor>> here instead?
    vector<shared_ptr<Sensor>> sensors;
public:
    void Add( /* parameters */ )
    {
           sensors.push_back(make_shared<Sensor>( /* parameters */ ));
    }

    vector<shared_ptr<Sensor>> GetBrokenSensors()
    {
          // Your logic goes here.
    }

    void RemoveSensor( /* some sort of Id */ )
    {
          // remove this sensor from sensors.
    }

    // rest of stuff
};
```

I have left a lot of open details here, like whether your sensors have shared or unique ownership, how exactly their life time is controlled, how are they identified etc.

Comment: I see your point in this, and i agree that this would be useful for this purpose, and probably in the future as well for similar things. We have had discussions about redoing this part of the code to something similar which you are describing. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

If you need to check for all the sensors regularly, so there is no way except looping over them like you did.

However, if what you need is to only spot the broken sensor, a better pattern to follow is the [observer design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), which simply lets every sensor class reports it's failure to the main component once it happens.

You can also find a C++ implementation for it [here](https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/observer.html).